# Meaning of $R(t)$ in FLRW metric

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, metric-tensor

In the [FLRW metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) what is the meaning of $R(t)$ from a geometric point of view? And from a physical point of view?

$$ds^2 = dt^2 - R^2(t) \left( \frac{d\bar r ^2}{1-\kappa \bar r^2} + \bar r ^2 d \Omega^2  \right)$$

Is $\bar r$ measuring comoving distances?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric#Reduced-circumference_polar_coordinates), which explains what it is in this case

Comment: $\bar r$ is dimensionless. $R(t)\bar r$ is proper distance, which makes $\bar r$ a comoving quantity, but it isn't distance because the units of distance are carried in $R(t)$. $\frac{R(t)\bar r}{a(t)}$ would be comoving distance

Comment: What is $a(t)$ in your comment? Thanks for your replies!

Comment: $a(t)$ is the scale factor as we normally define it. $R(t)$ is a scale factor that carries dimensions of length. This makes the coordinate $\bar r$ dimensionless. If we put the length dimensions back in $\bar r$, then we have to take them out of $R(t)$; $a(t)$ is that result. It is more of a literal scale factor and has more physical meaning, which is why we tend to use $a(t)$ more than $R(t)$

Comment: I don't know much about $a(t)$ since my lectures notes use $R(t)$. Is there a mathematical relation between these two scaling factors or it is just matter of dimensions?

Comment: It's just a matter of dimensions, but when you use $R(t)$, then $\kappa$ is restricted to -1,0,1 Whereas with $a(t)$, k can be anything, it's just the sign of k that indicates the curvature

Comment: I don't understand how "passing" the units from $R$ to $\bar r$ can change the possible values of $\kappa$

Comment: You don't just pass the units from $R$ to $\bar r$, the denominator in the $d\bar r^2$ term has to be dimensionless still, so $k$ picks up dimensions of inverse distance squared. In doing so, it keeps the sign from before, but its value has modifiers that allow it to become something other than +/-1 or 0

Comment: I guess you could say there is a formal mathematical relationship. But there's not normally a need to worry what it is. You normally define the metric in the way you want to use it and go from there. That eliminates the need to transform all your coordinates

Comment: What you are suggesting is: $1-\kappa \bar r = 1-\frac{\kappa a^2(t)}{R^2(t)} \frac{R^2(t)\bar r}{a^2(t)} = 1-kr_{\text{comoving}}$? If yes isn't k time dependent? Or is $\frac{ a(t)}{R(t)}$ time independent?

Comment: Yes sure, I'm just trying to make clear what is comoving and what is something else

Comment: What I'm saying is that $r^2=\frac{\bar r^2}{|k|}$ and $a^2(t)=|k|R^2(t)$. $k$ is time independent because it is defined as the Gaussian curvature of space when $a(t)=1$.

Comment: The scale factor makes a comoving or conformal value into a proper one. $a(t)r$ is proper distance, $r$ is comoving distance

Comment: Are you familiar with Rubakov's book? He seems to use $a(t)$ with spatial dimension

Comment: No, not familiar. There's nothing that says you can't switch $a$ and $R$, but conventionally $a$ is dimensionless

Comment: Yes sure... Just wanted to double check if you were familiar with it. Thank you very much... I think everything is clearer now!

Comment: Since we are in the discussion... What observer measure proper distance? And conformal distance?

Comment: Right now, proper distance and comoving distance are equal. But proper distance is that measured with a ruler, which means that all observers would measure proper distance